# MPMoviePlayerController current playing item details?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, currentitem

i am playing a audio stream url using MPMoviePlayerController, it works fine, is their any way to get the details of current playing track ..i mean song title, artist name etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: @Parth Bhatt helow, will you please help me

Answer (score 2):

Addt this ur .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *songLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *albumLabel;


- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(id)notification 
{
// Ask the music player for the current song.
MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

// Display the artist, album, and song name for the now-playing media item.
// These are all UILabels.
 self.songLabel.text   = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
 self.artistLabel.text = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
 self.albumLabel.text  = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];    
 // Display album artwork. self.artworkImageView is a UIImageView.
 CGSize artworkImageViewSize = self.artworkImageView.bounds.size;
 MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
 if (artwork != nil) 
 {
      self.artworkImageView.image = [artwork imageWithSize:artworkImageViewSize];
 }   
else
{
        self.artworkImageView.image = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;   is that musicPlayer is MPMoviePlayerController object?

Comment: but when i access the MPMoviePlayerController object inside this method, i got the error 
 "property 'musicPlayer' not found on object of type 'firstViewController' " ... i have given MPMoviePlayerController object as static, static MPMoviePlayerController *musicplayer=nil;

Comment: firstViewController is nothing but the class containing  MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: not that problem solved by just giving property and synthesize for player object, now for elf.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem; , nowPlayingItem is not getting?

Comment: property nowPlayingItem not found on object of type "MPMoviePlayerController *"

Comment: refer MPMusicPlayerController from here http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/

Comment: sorry, but i am talking about MPMoviePlayerController, not about MPMusicPlayerController..., i need something like this for MPMoviePlayerController

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerController` does not support getting ID3-based metadata out of the played stream. You will have to use `MPMusicPlayerController` (local content) or possibly `AVPlayer` (streamed content) to get that accomplished. Though I must admit that I am not entirely sure if `AVPlayer`/`AVPlayerItem` will actually get the job done - I have never tried it myself.

Comment: but i have an online http audio streaming using MPMoviePlayerController, is MPMusicPlayerController support online streaming? is their any other way to implement this...

Comment: okay then how will i access current playing item details in AVPlayer